A Question on the Definition of Cap Product
I am reading Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and have a naive question on cap product.For a certain simplex $[v_0,\cdots,v_k]$ we can arbitarily permutate the vertexs of the simplex(change the signal at most),for example,in the picture here,$\phi(\sigma|[v_0...v_l])\sigma|[v_l...v_k]$ can be permutated as $\pm\phi(\sigma|[v_k...v_{k-l}])\sigma|[v_{k-l}...v_0]$(notice that the simplex haven't been changed).So why can we guarantee that the result is invariant under permutation?(that is,cap product is well-defined)I find it highly nontrivial.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You cannot permute the vertices arbitaraly!! After permutation you get a different simplex.
